# write csv of nested for loop with if else

Tags: python, xml, csv

i am new to python and i learn a lot everyday . I have a specific folder that contains some xml file and i am parsing xml text of  PMID ,Date ,Title and Abstract   and i am  writing csv of for loop with if else statement but it not printing it gives error it how to write csv of for loop with if else condition

Here is my python Code :

```
import os 
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

path = '/home/shayez/Desktop/project/kk'

listfile = []
files = os.listdir(path)
for name in files:

    listfile.append(name)

pmdata = []    

for name2 in listfile:

        full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('project/kk',name2))
        dom = ET.parse(full_file)
        pmdat = dom.findall('PubmedArticle')
        pmdata.append(pmdat)                

def Print_Data ():

    header = ['PMID','Date','Title','Abstract']
    with open ('/home/shayez/Desktop/karim.csv','wt') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter ="\t" )
        writer.writerow(header)

    for d in pmdata:

                 for c in d :

                     PMID = c.find('MedlineCitation/PMID').text
                     title = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/ArticleTitle').text
                     Date = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/Year')
                     Date2 = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/MedlineDate')

                     Abstract = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract/AbstractText')

                     rows =  [PMID,Date,title,Abstract]

                     if Abstract is None :
                         print PMID,"\t",Date.text, "\t",title ,"\t", "No abstract Available"

                     elif Date2 is None:
                         print PMID,"\t",Date.text, "\t",title ,"\t",Abstract.text   

                     elif Date is None:
                         print PMID,"\t",Date2.text, "\t",title ,"\t",Abstract.text

                     else :
                         print PMID,"\t","No Date", "\t",title ,"\t", "No abstract Available"

                     rows =  [PMID,Date,title,Abstract]

                     writer.writerows(rows)

Print_Data()
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/shayez/Desktop/k.py", line 72, in <module>
    Print_Data()
  File "/home/shayez/Desktop/k.py", line 67, in Print_Data
    writer.writerows(rows)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: The second-to-last line of code is not possible. You already closed the file as soon as you dropped a level of indentation from your `with` block. Thats the point of the context manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need your `for` loop to be *inside* the `with` block, otherwise it will close `csvfile`:

```
def Print_Data ():

    header = ['PMID','Date','Title','Abstract']
    with open ('/home/shayez/Desktop/karim.csv','wt') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter ="\t" )
        writer.writerow(header)

        for d in pmdata:

             for c in d :

                     PMID = c.find('MedlineCitation/PMID').text
                     title = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/ArticleTitle').text
                     Date = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/Year')
                     Date2 = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/MedlineDate')

                     Abstract = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract/AbstractText')

                     rows =  [PMID,Date,title,Abstract]

                     # Other code

                     writer.writerows(rows)
```

Now that you've moved your `writer` inside your `with` block, we can address the other issue. `writer.writerows()` expects an iterable of `row` objects. Your `rows` object is a *single* row, throwing an exception. To accomplish what you want to do, you'll have to collect all of the `row` entries you want to write into a `list`:

```
with open ('/home/shayez/Desktop/karim.csv','wt') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter ="\t" )
        writer.writerow(header)
        rows = []

        for d in pmdata:
            for c in d:

                # code to get PMID, Date, title, Abstract

                rows.append([PMID, Date, title, Abstract])

        # Note that this is after your two for loops
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

The other option you have is to use `writer.writerow(row)` *inside* the `for` loop on each `row`

Comment: now it is showing this error     "    writer.writerows(rows)
_csv.Error: sequence expected"

Comment: You will want `writer.writerow(row)` because you are not handing the `writer` *multiple* rows, you are only giving it one. I'll edit my answer